# Upcoming Umrah, went on BC but still spotting

Tags: women, hajj, menses, umrah

Taking birth control pill to delay the period because of upcoming Umrah trip next week But unfortunately started spotting so does this mean I can’t offer salah, fast or do tawaf? It’s very light period so want to know how much spotting does it take to consider women unclean to perform salah?

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as a minimum amount of spotting. Once menses is recognized by its attributes it is menses no matter how few it is and all related rulings apply.

And menses only ends when there's no trace of it. And one can go on with his worship after taking ghusl.